# Need help with SQL query - out join solution?

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I have a database table of email addresses.
I want to query it based on a set of strings.

I do not just want the query results to return those email addresses contained in the set of strings - that would be simple.

Rather, I want to get back all of the strings used in the query, along with a Boolean field that tells me if it is in the table or not.  e.g.:
   joe@joe.com  TRUE
   sam@sam.com  TRUE
   jim@jim.com  FALSE

I have on solution (joining an 'In' query with a 'Not In' query) - but I was hoping for something better.

(Yes, I realize I can figure it out without the database by doing the simple query then removing the found items from the set of query strings)

Comment: I would try UNION as in the following. It is close to what you are doing and i am not sure about the syntax but you probably get the idea. `SELECT email_address, "TRUE" FROM table WHERE email_address IN ('a@b.com', 'b@c.com') 
UNION
SELECT email_address, "FALSE" FROM table WHERE email_address NOT in ('a@b.com', 'b@c.com') `

Comment: For what database?  SQL stands for "STRUCTURED query language", not "STANDARDIZED ..."

Comment: which database server? The question is ambiguous as is.

Comment: I am working with mysql.

Comment: I mistyped my question ... I should have said my solution was unioning an 'in' query with a 'not in' query - as Sai came up with

Answer (score 1):

Put the addresses you are querying for into a (temporary) table, then LEFT JOIN the email address table to it.

```
SELECT
  r.email_address,
  CASE WHEN e.email_address IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS is_present
FROM requested_emails r
  LEFT JOIN email_addresses e ON r.email_address = e.email_address
```

Comment: Thanks ... yes, I believe a temp table would do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @CrappyStr varchar(10)
set @CrappyStr = 'dummy'

select @CrappyStr AS SearchString
, email_address
, CASE WHEN charindex(@CrappyStr, email_address) > 0 THEN 'True'
 ELSE 'False' END AS [BOO-lean]
from SnarkyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that SQL does not have a boolean type. Here I'm using a string.

```
SELECT email_address, NVL( sq.present, 'FALSE' ) AS present
  FROM mytable t
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT email_address, 'TRUE' AS present 
                FROM mytable
               WHERE email_address in ( ... your list here ... )
            ) sq ON sq.email_address = t.email_address
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was trying to get to ... unfortunately I can't get it to work for me on mysql.  I swapped in the IFNULL function for NVL, but I don't think that should do anything bad.  It complained that email_address was ambiguous, so I went ahead and asked for both t.email and sq.email.  It still only gave me the email records in the table.